# Does the inequality of repeated limits at a certain point confirm the limit to not exist at that particular point while dealing in two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

In two variable functions we know that if limit exists at a certain point through all the possible paths and if repeated limits at that particular points exist then the two repeated limits are always equal.
So can we say that if repeated limits exists at some point but are not equal then the general limit of that function will never exist at that particular point....
Thanks in advance for helping me with this one.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)\ne\lim_{y\to b}\lim_{x\to a}$? Then yes, the limit $\lim_{x\to a, y\to b} f(x,y)$ does not exists.